# Open Camera, now add UIImage from Saved Phot Albums or Photo Liberary

Tags: iphone

I am currently working on interior Decoration Iphone Application, That needs Camera. So when camera is open I want to get UIImage from SavedPhotoAlbums/Photo Library, then want to show it on Camera while Camera is Still open in Background...                                       Any Suggestion and Help. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can nOt Open Photo Library while Camera is open, Because Camera + Photo Album/Library comes under Class UIImagePicker. So if one is already running you cannot open another.

If you want to do That?
den

Save Objects that are already there on Camera with Their Frame and Close Camera.

Then

Open Photo Album/Library, Pick an Image from Library, Open Camera again and show Saved Objects + Selected Image on Camera.

any Query or Suggestion? You are Welcome